# How to filter root collection on the basis of values in the sub collection in Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore database in Swift iOS, I want to filter the list of root collection on the basis of values available in each documents' subcollection?

Root Collection --> Posts --> documents--> Subcollection--> document--> fieldvalue

The value of the "fieldvalue" has to decide the list of documents in root collection posts

I tried this below, but it is not working as required.

```
let postsRef = Firestore.firestore()
    .collection("posts")
    .document()
    .collection("comments")
    .whereField("comment_author_id", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
    .whereField("l1", isEqualTo: true)
    .limit(to: 50)
```

please assist

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it. Beside that, what is not working? You have added only a query. What's not working the way you expect.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added the screen shot, basically there is a post and comment, all i want to enlist the posts where the current user has commented and these comments are in the subcollection of posts along with user id of the user who commented

Comment: Please add also a screenshot of a document within your `comments` subcollection.

Comment: @AlexMamo added the comments subcollection as well

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not working as required because when calling:

```
.document()
```

Right after:

```
.collection("posts")
```

Without passing any argument, Firestore doesn't really know which document you are reffering to. If you want to get all comments within your `2czkDrrg4gHgXbCID69u` document, then you should pass that id to the `document()` function like this:

```
.collection("posts").document("2czkDrrg4gHgXbCID69u")
```

Remember, Firestore queries are shallow, can get comments only from the collection that the query is run against. A single query may only use properties of documents in a single collection.

If you want to get all comments within all your documents that exist in your `posts` collection, then you should use a [Firestore collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). Please note, that all subcollections must have the same (comments) name.

Comment: thanks for the guidance I will work with it right away